# Sobolev Embedding on Finite Tube

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $B=[0,T]\times Y$, here $Y$ denotes  a closed manifold. Suppose we use the product metric on this finite tube.

We can have the following inequality
$$\|s\mid_{t\times Y}\|_{L^2_1(Y)}\leq Const \|s\|_{L^2_2(B)},$$
where $Const$ is independent on $t\in[0,T]$.

$L^2_k$ denotes the $k$-th. Sobolev norm in $L^2$ sense.

As Piotr Hajlasz pointed out by the standard trace theorem.

**Q**: Can we let the Constant does not depend on the $T$, or just depends on the volume of $B$.

Comment: In your notation, I assume $L^2_1$ is the Sobolev space for 1 derivatives measured in $L^2$? If so, yes, it should hold.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: I believe what the OP had in mind is to look at the $L^2_1$ norm of the trace of $s$ on $\{t\} \times Y$ where $t \in [0,T]$. At least that's the interpretation I wrote my previous comment under.

Comment: I removed my comment because I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, that is true.**
This is a consequence of the classical [Trace Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator)
 for Sobolev spaces. The proof can be found in any textbook on Sobolev spaces for example in Evans' [Partial Differential Equations](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=RT&pg7=JOUR&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=evans&s5=partial&s6=&s7=&s8=Books&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=2597943). The usual statement of the trace theorem deals with traces of 
$T:W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to L^p(\partial\Omega)$,
but the proof would also give traces 
$T:W^{1,p}([0,T]\times Y)\to L^p(\{ t\}\times Y)$. If $u\in W^{2,p}$, then the derivative is in $W^{1,p}$ so the trace of the derivative is in $L^p$ and since the derivative of the trace is the trace of the derivative (roughly speaking) we 
obtain the trace $T:W^{2,p}([0,T]\times Y)\to W^{1,p}(\{ t\}\times Y)$.